# Environment Variables not working properly or Java not installing correctly

Tags: java, windows, path, cmd, environment-variables

I'm going through a self training course for a company I just started with as a QA. The "mandatory" installs apply to everyone whether developer or QA. I'm needing to install an older version of Java JDK 1.6.x and my guide says to create a directory for all the tools they want me to install.

I had to create a dev/tools directory called devel under my username, within it I put a gitsrc directory for source code that we share and a tools directory as well. I then had to create Environment Variables (system-wide) for the tools folder. I named the tools one (where I need to dumb all of the installs) DEV_TOOLS and put the path value to 
C:\Users\myusername\devel\tools <----this part is correct.

I then created an additional JAVA_HOME variable with value of %DEV_TOOLS%\jdk1.6.x for the specific version. After the install I have to append the PATH variable so that the %JAVA_HOME%\bin is added in there as well.

I run into 2 issues:

1st when I try to download JDK 1.6.x and specify path as %DEV_TOOLS%\jdk 1.6.x it says unavailable, so I just used the long form C:\users\myusername\devel\tools\jdk1.6.x as mentioned before then it goes fine.

2nd after I install it I need to verify that it worked properly so I run cmd and type *java -version* to see if its correct. It doesn't display the newly downloaded version but an older version of jdk 1.6.x.

So what am I doing wrong? Sorry for the length of this question, but I figured better to be detailed. Any help/recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `echo %PATH%` in cmd and see if you get the right path of Java and it is the only one.

Comment: I tried that and there is only the path I put, I don't see another that is the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is detecting a different version of Java.
Instead of Appending %DEV_TOOLS%\jdk6\bin to PATH, prepend it to PATH. Order matters.

To prepend Java without the variables, you can do the following:

```
PATH=C:\Path\To\Java\bin;...
```

In your case you want something like:

```
PATH=%DEV_TOOLS%\jdk6\bin;...
```

Of course, be sure DEV_TOOLS is defined

Comment: I checked all of the paths and JAVA isn't mentioned until the last one and that's the one I put it. Is it possible its somewhere somehow?

Comment: At the Windows command prompt type 'where java'. It should with the path its picking up

Comment: okay I get the path I created as well as C:\Windows\System32\java.exe, thanks for helping me find that. where do I got from here though as far as either getting rid of it or fixing it?

Comment: At this point, follow the instructions in my answer. All in all, prepend the path to the Java version you'd like to use to PATH

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it has helped solve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: You've been incredibly helpful and I'm sure it is the correct answer...unfortunately I feel like a simpleton (and may be one) because I'm somehow not doing the prepend correctly. I'm assuming this is done from cmd line, I input PATH=%DEV_TOOLS%\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;but am I supposed to put the other path where the ... is at? I'm sorry for my lack of understanding/knowledge.

Comment: You can do it via My Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings.
On advanced tab, press Environment variables. Add your variables e.g. DEV_TOOLS as system variable. You'll also find the 'Path' variable there. You need to prepend the path to Java bin there

Comment: Okay, my apologies, you're answer does work. Thank you so much for your help and patience. 1,000,000 Brownie Points to you! You helped me out of a pickle for sure.